# Probability of a target

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose the probability of hitting a target is $1/4$. If eight shots are fired at the target, what is the probability that the target is hit at least twice.

I am learning this topic by myself. I am not sure how to solve this problem. I suppose that we would subtract it from one. Here is the work.

$$P(X \geq 2) = 1-P(X < 2)$$

$$ = 1- \binom{8}{0} (0.25)^{0} (0.75)^{8}-\binom{8}{1} (0.25)^{1}(0.75)^{7}$$

I was wondering is this correct. Can you explain if there is an easier way please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is fine, except that the probability of missing is $0.75$, so your $(1)$'s should be $0.75$'s and you lost a $5$ in the last term-the $0.2$ should be $0.25$

Comment: Is that because of $1-0.25$ $=$ $0.75$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Your first term (after the $1$)is calculating the chance that all $8$ shots miss, which should be $(\frac 34)^8$.  Your second is the chance that one hits ($0.25$) and the others miss ($0.75^8$) times the number of ways to choose the one that hits.

Comment: In the second, should it be $(0.75)^{7}$ and not $(0.75)^{8}$?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Your answer is now correct.